# Python function that will find and count vowels in a given string

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code with python that will find and count the number of vowels in any given string. My function prints out 0 vowels no matter what. Any tips?

```
txt = input("Type text: ").lower()

def findVowels():
    global txt
    vowels = 0
    for letter in txt:
        if letter == 'aeiouy':
            vowels += 1
    return vowels


print(findVowels())
```

Number of vowels = 0 no matter what

Comment: This is may not be code related but technically, "y" is not a vowel.

Comment: @CodeRed In English, "y" is considered as a vowel when it is not the first letter of syllable within a word.  I.e. it is a consonant in the word "yup", but a vowel in the word "symbol".

Comment: I'd love to explain but this is not the best platform for that. Good day sir!

Comment: In my language, Norwegian "y" is a vowel so that's why it's in there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
def findVowels(txt):
    return sum(1 for t in txt if t in 'aeiouy')
```

Comment: Double `def` and you can even do: `return sum(t in 'aeiouy' for t in txt)`

Comment: Why couldn't you?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thanks for the heads up, and you can, but tends to be slower do to conversion of `bool` to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking if the `letter` is equal to the entire string `'aeiouy'`.  Instead check if `letter` is **`in`** the string.

```
if letter in 'aeiouy':
```

Also, you can avoid using global variable by passing the input text to the function.

```py
txt = input("Type text: ").lower()

def findVowels(txt):
    vowels = 0
    for letter in txt:
        if letter in 'aeiouy':
            vowels += 1
    return vowels


print(findVowels(txt))
```